# Password immediatly expires after using reset password for users

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm managing a portal for a small company in azure active directory and one of my users has lost access to their account. However, when I try to reset their password the new password immediately expires, leaving them locked out of their account. Currently the only workaround is deleting their account, have them re-register and then add them to all groups they used to belong to. This is very tedious and time-consuming, so I was shopping to find a solution here.

Thanks in advance!

Wouter

Comment: are you sure it's expiring? When you reset a password in AAD it does need to be changed at first login, so  you need to try logging into say the Office portal or similar web front end to change it.

Comment: To many missing information, is it a cloud only account? is it synced from on prem? do you have any password policies in place? where are you resetting the password? do you have SSPR enabled? do you have password write back enabled? where is the user trying to login and receiving the error? what is the actual error message?